# iOS - iframe is capturing scroll events even though it doesn't need to scroll

Tags: ios, css, iframe, scroll, overflow

My page is composed of one iframe and some extra content that overflows the viewport:

[image: Page structure]

When the user tries to scroll on the iframe, the scrolling event is **triggered inside the iframe** and, for security reasons, the parent window doesn't know anything about it.
But because the iframe is taller than its content, it doesn't need any scrolling and thus should **propagate the scroll event to the parent window**.

It works as expected in [this example](https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bckld/iframe/working-example.html).

But as soon as the iframe is wrapped inside a div with `overflow: auto` or `scroll`, it doesn't work anymore on iOS (11.3.1), as you can see in [this other example](https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bckld/iframe/parent-auto.html).

Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help appreciated!

#### What I tried

- `overflow: hidden` on the iframe
- `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` on the iframe
- `scrolling="no"` attribute on the iframe tag
- `pointer-events: none` on the iframe fixed the scrolling problem, but you [can't interact with the iframe anymore](https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bckld/iframe/parent-no-pointer-events.html)

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` on any parent div that has a defined height fixed the problem.

Here's a working version of the example initially broken : [link](https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bckld/iframe/parent-auto-fixed.html).